# Disable menuItem while ModalDialog is shown and enable when window is closed?

Tags: wpf, window, menuitem

I am implementing an application, and if I click on a menu item:

```
 <MenuItem Name="menuAlgemeneGeg" Header="Algemene gegevens" Click="AlgemeneGegevensClick" />
```

the method is :

```
private void AlgemeneGegevensClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ToetsBeheerViewModel vm = (ToetsBeheerViewModel)this.DataContext;
            EditAlgemeneGegevens window = new EditAlgemeneGegevens(vm.Examination);
            window.ShowDialog();
            menuAlgemeneGeg.IsEnabled = false;

        }
```

Now what I want is, that when you click on it the menuitem is disabled. But from the moment the user closes this window it must be enabled again. I can disable the menuitem but can't change this back to enable it.
Someone who can help me out please?

Comment: in this code : your menu will be disabled only when you close EditAlgemeneGegevens window because the lines after the ShowDialog() will be executed after the window closed,

Comment: when you use showdialog you will not be able to work in your main window why you disable the menu in your main window !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can handle window closed event.. and enable menu in even handler

```
private void AlgemeneGegevensClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ToetsBeheerViewModel vm = (ToetsBeheerViewModel)this.DataContext;
            EditAlgemeneGegevens window = new EditAlgemeneGegevens(vm.Examination);
             window.Closed += new EventHandler(Window_Closed);
            window.ShowDialog();
            menuAlgemeneGeg.IsEnabled = false;

        }

 void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             menuAlgemeneGeg.IsEnabled = true;
        }
```

Comment: the Window_Closed work when the main window be closed but If I have understand his problem he want to enable this menu when EditAlgemeneGegevens be closed

Comment: EditAlgemeneGegevens is also a window.. because he is able to call showdialog method... so he can handle closed event too

Comment: if you mean that the Window_Closed is in EditAlgemeneGegevens then this is incorrect because the menuAlgemeneGeg is not a child of this window !!

Comment: bathineni is correct. You can attach a closed event listener on the EditAlgemeneGegevens window inside your parent class no problem. However Akrem is right that control won't return from `ShowDialog()` until the window is closed... so you need to put `menuAlgemeneGeg.IsEnabled = false` *before* the call to `ShowDialog()`. Alternatively you could call `window.Show()` instead and not worry about it being a dialog.